# How to preserve the state of a stateful service during deployments in Service fabric?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have a stateful service and other couple of stateless services that runs under same Service fabric cluster and under same solution.
When the deploymnet of the soln occurs, any chance that state of the stateful service gets lost ?Or just an upgarde happens and will the state is preserved?
is there any configurations i should do to preserve the state?

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of Reliable Collections in Azure Service Fabric stateful services is that you do not have to worry about things like data loss during rolling updates caused by deployments. The whole point of using Service Fabric is to facilitate high availably reliable (stateful) services.

Stateful services have their data replicated, you do not need to worry for dataloss and you do not have to do anything to preserve state.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if this is true or I am doing something wrong. When we deploy, it looks the memory is getting cleared. We don't persist to the disk (hasPersistedState=false). Any ideas what could be going wrong?